# Aliens target wrong planet, causing life on Earth rather than destroying it

Tags: story-identification

Trying to recall a short story I read decades ago. As best I recall, in an desperate effort to defeat humanity in a war they are losing, aliens send piloted bombs back in time to destroy the Earth before life has started. Miscalculation causes destruction of planet into asteroid belt and creates conditions for life on Earth.

The story was from perspective of a genetically engineered pilot of the bomb as it flew back in time to its suicidal goal.

I think the title was simply 'T' - the name of the pilot of the bomb - but trying to search internet for a title like that is not working out too well. Even tried 'shortest title for a story'.

Answer (score 27):

The story is indeed called "T" and it's by Brian W Aldiss. I have a copy in his collection *Space, Time and Nathaniel*, but you can find a bibliography for it on the [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51078).

You've misremembered it somewhat. The alien pilot doesn't create life on Earth -- he destroys the *wrong* planet, because they don't realise that the charts they're using already have the effect of T's mission (and those of his colleagues, including a near miss that creates the asteroid belt) included in them. Primitive life already exists on Earth and is unaffected by the destruction of a different planet in the solar system.